# How do I find out the gateway IP in shell?

Tags: router, ping, traceroute, ifconfig

How do I find out the IP address of the gateway using unix bash command line?

While usually it will be `192.168.1.1`, it might occasionally be `192.168.0.1` or something else depending on what router I connect to.

Comment: What shell?  Are you checking from Windows 10, MacOS, Linux, AIX, etc?

Comment: @BrianStevens: bash on linux or macos

Comment: oops.  Meant to make that a comment.  Do you need to get it from the shell itself or just find it for the machine?

Comment: @BrianStevens: I want a command line incantation, no GUI.

Comment: Please try (for linux):
ip route | grep default
or (for Mac):
netstat -nr | grep default

Comment: On my MacOS in terminal, I used netstat -nr | grep default and see: default 10.0.2.2 UGSc en0 (en0 is my network interface)

Comment: This question is a dupplicate for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/show-gateway-ip-address-when-performing-ifconfig-command

Comment: @OutOfBound: there is no `ip` command on macos, so, no, that answer does not help me, sorry.

Comment: @BrianStevens: thanks, it helps, but not solves the problem because it's a different command for each platform ;-(

Answer (score 2):

## [Install `ip` on mac](https://superuser.com/q/687310/98857)

```sh
brew install iproute2mac
```

## [Get the gateway IP address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23383/31443)

```sh
ip route show | grep default | cut -d' ' -f 3
```

## Check internet connection

```sh
for h in $(ip route show|grep default|cut -d' ' -f 3) google.com; do
  echo
  echo ===$h===
  ping -c 5 $h || break
done
```

Comment: Two processes, `grep` and `cut`, can be replaced by one (`awk`).

Comment: @GregA.Woods: I know, but I never learned `awk`, and perl looks like overkill here ;-)